# Error running Angular app: "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I update all packages to Angular 5 , but when i try to get `localhost:4200`
and in console i have an error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
"let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. ("<template #innerView></template>
<template #template [ERROR ->]let-ctx>
    <template [swapCmp]="ctx.component" [swapCmpBindings]="ctx.bindings" [swapCmpProjectable"): ng:///ModalModule/ModalOverlay.html@1:20
    at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:684)
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24530)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33917)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33892)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33794)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33794)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33664)
    at Object.then (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:673)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33663)
```

`webpack: Compiled successfully` in console.

What can be the problem?

It looks like old version of Angular

Comment: are you using `<template #template></template>` instead of `<ng-template #template></ng-template>`?

Comment: That is not the problem with Angular version, problem with code

Comment: Have you modified polyfills.ts at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me help is to uninstall `angular2 -modal` and install `ngx-modialog`, and than change packages in project.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says `"let-" is only supported on ng-template elements.` So if you are using `let` in any other element instead of `ng-template`,then you will be getting this error. And you are using let in `template`, then please change the `template` element to `ng-template` for `Angular-5`

Comment: I should change `template` to `ng-template` on html?

Comment: @HardExploder Exactly

Comment: @ Ramesh Rajendran not helped

Comment: Yes
For me help is to uninstall angular2 -modal and install ngx-modialog, and than change packages in project.

Comment: @HardExploder Could you please update your HTML code in your question?

Comment: too much pages to attach

Comment: @HardExploder just show me only `ModalOverlay.html` page code

Comment: i don't have this page in my project

Comment: You are getting this error on that page only. SO if it's a third party package, then you should update it for Angular5. Or you need to do manual change in that html page. That's a Solution.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-template` is Angular4.

Try `template` instead of `ng-template`